# How to specify what network to connect to automatically?

Tags: wireless, networking, 13.10, xubuntu

I'm on Xubuntu 13.10, I can connect to two different networks, `x` and `y`, I have passwords to both network and I can switch between them at will.

When Xubuntu starts, it automatically connect to `y`,  I want it to connect to `x`  unless I manually choose `y`.

Note that when I was on Windows 7, I had the same issue, now that I'm on Linux I hope that a bash script or something will do the trick.

Comment: What do you use to manage your networks in Xfce?

Comment: @Wilf [network gnome manager](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/NetworkManager)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Gnome's NetworkManager, it should be easy.

Click the arrow next to `y`'s network in the Wireless part of Network settings:
[image: The arrow is to the right of the network name]

Then select <kbd>Settings...</kbd>

Then look under the <kbd>General</kbd> tab, and untick:
[image: 'Automatically connect to this network when it is available']